# Python flack-Socketio getting Werkzeug Assertion Error in Logs

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio, werkzeug, python-socketio

I am working on python socketio where is use Flask. i getting below error on command prompt after client disconnect with server.
I am seeing an error from Werkzeug in the logs of my application, but it doesn't seem to effect the functioning of my app.

```
192.*.*.* - - [27/Sep/2023 16:58:17] "GET /websocket/v1/?EIO=4&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 364, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 330, in execute
    write(b"")
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 255, in write
    assert status_set is not None, "write() before start_response"
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The app seems to function fine.

below is my Python code.

```
from threading import Thread
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

class FlaskSocketServer(object):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    sio = SocketIO(app, async_mode='threading', path="/websocket/v1/")
    websocketSendID = "ABCDEFG-HIJ"
    ticket_dir = None
    websocketAuth = "test01"
    websocketPass = "1234567890"
    apiUrl = None

    def __init__(self):
        
        @self.sio.on('connect')
        def handle_connect():
            print("socket.io connection start.")

        @self.sio.on('disconnect')
        def handle_disconnect():
            print("socket.io disconnect.")

    def Start(self, hostIP, port, ticket_dir,apiUrl):
       thread = Thread(target=self.__Start, args=(hostIP,
                                          port,
                                          ticket_dir,
                                          apiUrl))
       thread.start()
    
    def __Start(self, hostIP, port, ticket_dir, apiUrl):
        self.apiUrl = apiUrl
        self.ticket_dir = ticket_dir  
        print("Server Running")
        self.app.run(host=hostIP, port=port)
```

Has anyone else seen this?

Thanks

Comment: Werkzeug does not natively support WebSocket. Depending on what version you are using you may see errors after a client disconnects. I have not noticed any errors with recent versions, however, except when running in debug mode. My thinking is that this is a development web server, so these are more an annoyance than a deal breaker. i give a much higher priority to the production use cases with Gunicorn.